# jQuery like attribute not equal selector with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I do something similar as [jQuery attribute not equal selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) with the "html()" value ?

Something like : `$("option[html!='No EXT']").remove();` <--- This don't work. (Html is not an attribute)

Comment: The contents of an element are not an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd go with the `:not` and `:contains` selectors here -

```
$("option:not(:contains('No EXT'))").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to loop through each option element and check its html.

```
$('option').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).html() !== 'No EXT' ) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: This will remove the one == 'No EXT', but it work if you remove the first "!". Thank you a lot